# Interface Builder could not open the document Main.storyboard" because it does not exist

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to run my flutter app on macos but any time I try ran it I get the above problem in vscode.

```
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
=== BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
/* com.apple.ibtool.errors */
/Users/norbertkross/Desktop/projectUpdates/05--01--2019/flutteriOSFold/fun_holidays/ios/Runner/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard: error: Interface Builder could not open the document Main.storyboard" because it does not exist.
Could not build the application for the simulator.
```

I have built this successfully before and I dont remember changing anything in the directory am being directed to

Comment: Is this project under versioning? Are you sure you din't any modifications?

Comment: yes I have not made any modifications